# A. V. Oppenheim Problem $(1.14)$

Tags: continuous-signals

> **Problem 1.14)** Consider a periodic signal :
> $$
> x(t):=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
> 1, & 0 \leq t \leq 1 \\
> -2, & 1<t<2
> \end{array}\right.
> $$
> with period $T=2$. The derivative of this signal is related to the "impulse train"
> $$
> g(t):=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(t-2 k)
> $$
> with period $T=2 .$ It can be shown that
> $$
> \frac{d x(t)}{d t}=A_{1} g\left(t-t_{1}\right)+A_{2} g\left(t-t_{2}\right)
> $$
> Determine the values of $A_{1}, t_{1}, A_{2},$ and $t_{2}$.

I checked on wikipedia the impulse train and it seem's too advanced for chapter $1$. I was wondering how we can plot $g(t)$. The solution manual only offers the graph without how it is plotted.

Comment: I don't think "wikipedia puts it complicatedly" is a good metric for "possible to answer" :) You can't "really" plot something composed of delta diracs, you can only place placeholders where they are. Do you understand what $\delta$ is?

Comment: other than that, the question is really just asking you to compare the $dx/dt$ equation to the definition of $x(t)$. I think you might be overthinking things.

Comment: You are right, so as a first step I convert the piecewise function to unit step functions? @MarcusMüller

Comment: I don't see a step function being involved here, but I might be imagining the way to a solution differently in my head than you do!

Comment: I am really interested in your method. @MarcusMüller

Comment: well, $dx/dt$ is really boring for but very few points. so, at these points $A_1g(t-t_1)+A_2g(t-t_2)$ must be "special". I just insert the definition of $g$ into that.